# Lagrange mean value theorem Directional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $v$ such that $\lVert u\rVert=1$ the directional derivative
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}(a+tv)
$$

exists for every $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $t\in[0,1]$. I want to prove that there exist $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that:
$$
h(a+v)-h(a)=\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}(a+\alpha v)
$$

My idea was to use Lagrange theorem for multivariate functions that gives me

Let $g(t):[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $g(t)=h(a+tv)$, then $g(0)=h(a)$ and $g(1)=h(a+v)$. By unidimensional Lagrange mean value theorem I found:

$$
g(1)-g(0)=g'(\alpha)=dh(a+\alpha v)\cdot v=\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}(a+tv)
$$

Is existence of directional derivatives sufficient for this approach?

Any help or suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: If you, in addition, know that $h$ is continuous, then your function $g$ satisfies the assumption of the one dimensianal mean value theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) so the conclusion is correct (which is explicitly mentioned in the wiki page, also). The question whether continuity is implied by your assumption is a bit tricky.

Comment: But for the application of the one dimensional mean value theorem you only need directional continuity (i.e. you must know that $g$ is continuous) which is implied by your assumptions, also.

Comment: I have corrected some misprints. My perplexity arose primarily from the fact $f$ is not assumed to be continuous.

Comment: while you are at it you may want to replace $u$ in the first line by $v$ - that's what I would assume, at least.